# Get available and booked time in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in mysql (shop_details,booking)

shop_details

```
id      shop_id     open_time       close_time
1       1           09:00Am         09:00Pm
2       5           10:00Am         09:00Pm
```

booking

```
id      shop_id     start_time      end_time
1       1           10:30am         11:10Am
1       5           02:00pm         02:45pm
```

Now I want if I want to know about shop_id (1) then I want to get booked time (after shop open time) and avaliable time (till shop close) with every half hour, for example I want following result

```
shop_id     start_time      end_time    status
1           09:00am         09:30am     avaliable
1           09:30am         10:00am     avaliable
1           10:00am         10:30am     avaliable
1           10:30am         11:10am     booked
1           11:10am         11:40am     avaliable
...
1           08:30am         09:00pm     booked
```

Comment: Show your previous tries to achieve it, your code, etc etc etc. Remember SO is not a coding army, its a place for help you, no a place who works for you.

Comment: why there are sometimes bookings for 45 minutes, sometimes for 40. and You want to show avaiable if there is at least 30 minutes of not booked time and show only this 30 minutes? why not 50 if for example 50 is free time not booked?

Comment: your data are strange. what is the difference between `id` and `shop_id`? where the last row of the expected comes from?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: can we know what is data type of Start time and End time? and further what if we would have booking for 15 min what we should do with remaining?

Comment: @kirangadhe :  if we booking for 15 minutes then that time should display as booked time

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of times -- then you can get the information using a `join` or correlated subquery:

```
select t.tme,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from booking b
                          where b.start_time <= t.tme and
                                b.end_time > t.tme
                         )
             then 'booked' else 'available'
        end) as status
from (select cast('00:00' as time) as tme union all
      select cast('00:30' as time) as t union all
      select cast('01:00' as time) as t union all
      . . .
      select cast('23:50' as time) as t
     ) t join
     (select sd.*
      from shop_details sd
      where sd.shop_id = 1
     ) sd1
     on t.tme >= sd1.open_time and
        t.tme <= sd1.close_time;
```

Answer (score -1):

first, use while function to create a loop that will repeat the code until reaching close time,
inside while function, u can use IF statement to make Availability status base on dates

goold luck